# 2D Array Fibonacci Square - Java

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

Write a method that finds a closed square path (a loop) within a matrix. The closed path should be clockwise, it can start at any point of the matrix (any element), and contain elements which form a Fibonacci series.

```
int[][] arr = {
    {4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7},
    {2, 4, 5, 21, 0, 3, 6},
    {4, 5, 2, 13, 8, 5, 7},
    {4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7},
}
```

This for example should return true, because

```
1  1 2
21 0 3
13 8 5
```

forms a square I am looking for.

I just can't quite get my head around an algorithm for this problem.

Comment: _This for example should return true..._ **What** should return true? The array??

Comment: @B001ᛦ yes, i am sorry the method that checks if such square exists should return true, i will edit my question.

Comment: what is unclear about it. it should return true becuase in the input a square, that is having his sides form a fibonacci sequnce, is found, and i gave example what a possible square can look like

Comment: @AlexanderPol Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @maloomeister sadly I can't even think of how to start. So no, I haven't tried anything so far :(.

Comment: The requirements are still not completely clear to me. Is the `0` always in the center, and does the rest of the sequence always start top right of the square, clockwise? Is the square always 3x3? Or can it be 4x4 aswell?

Comment: first, try to detect the sequence on a single row

Comment: @maloomeister the squre has minimum size of 2x2(it can be bigger), the sequence should start from top left corner of the square, it doesnt matter whats inside the square, only the borders should form a sequence.

Comment: So, it can be **any** part of the fibonacci sequence? I.e. it may start from 144?

Comment: @maloomeister it may start from any fibonacci number

Comment: I think the requirement is to find a closed  square path (a loop)  within a matrix. The close path should be clockwise, it can start at any point of the matrix (any element), and contain elements which form a Fibonacci series.

Comment: @c0der yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some kind of [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (or [wall follower algorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze-solving_algorithm#Wall_follower) which is also a DFS) to find all NxN clockwise paths, starting from any element in the matrix. 
N should be bigger than 2 and not bigger than the smaller dimension of the matrix.
For each path found you need to check if it contains a Fibonacci series.

Comment: thx, i will update my question with the answer once I am ready.

Comment: Please don't edit the question in a way that makes the answer invalid. It might be better to post a new question and leave a comment here.